# ADFS 2.0 TokenLifetime and NotBefore / NotOnOrAfter

Tags: adfs

Based on documentation and articles, the TokenLifetime property of a RP is:

- 60 minutes when set to 0 (this is the default)
- Number of minutes (480 max) where 1 is 1 min, 2 is 2 min and so on

I am fairly certain that the NotBefore / NotOnOrAfter attributes in the  element of the SAMLResponse should have a time difference equal to the TokenLifetime.

After doing some testing with a Web Browser SSO profile that makes use of HTTP Redirect/Post binding methods, I am noting the following that is not consistent with my TokenLifetime property definition:

- 0 = 60 mins **(Good)**
- > 0 is hours (not mins), so 1 = 60 mins, 2 = 120 mins,... **(Bad)**

Is there some other attribute or setting that influences the time difference for the NotBefore / NotOnOrAfter attributes? Are my assertions incorrect?

Ultimately I need the time difference in the NotBefore / NotOnOrAfter attributes to be 3-4 mins.

Thanks!

**Update**: I tested things using ADFS 3.0 and it works the way I expected that it should (ie TokenLifetime 1 = 1 min ...) so 2.0 remains a mystery!